# Efetuar cálculo Quantidade x Valor entre inputs em carrinho de compra

Tags: php, jquery

Estou tentando efetuar um cálculo em meu carrinho de compra, por exemplo: quantidade x preço jogando o resultado em outro input, consegui fazer para o primeiro produto, mas nos demais não está funcionando.

O script que tenho em php é esse:

```html
<form class="container">
  <div class="cartContent clearfix" method="post" action="#">
 <div id="cartContent">
   <div class="item">
  <div class="cart_img"><img src="<?php echo "../".$list['caminho_thumbs']; ?>" alt="" width="60" /></div>
  <a href="" class="product_name">
  <span><?php echo $list['nome']; ?></span> 
  <small><strong>CÓDIGO: <?php echo $list['codigo_iabv']; ?></strong></small>
  </a> 
  <a href="orcamentos.php?del=<?php echo (int)$id; ?>" class="remove_item"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
  <div class="qty">
    <input type="text" value="1" name="total" maxlength="3" id="total" />
    </span></div>
  <div class="qty">
    <?php if ( isset($_SESSION["quantidade"][$id]) && ($_SESSION["quantidade"][$id] != 0) ){ ?>
    <input type="text" id="quantidade" name="quantidade" maxlength="3" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["quantidade"][$id] ?>" id_qtd="<?php echo $list['id_produto'] ?>"  />
    <?php } else { ?>
    <input type="text" id="quantidade" name="quantidade" value="<?php echo $QTD; ?>" class="input" id_qtd="<?php echo $list['id_produto']; ?>" />
    <?php }  ?>&nbsp; x &nbsp;
     <input type="text" value="1" name="valor_unitario" id="valor_unitario" />
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

O script que tenho para fazer o cálculo é esse:

```
function id(el) {
    return document.getElementById(el);
}

function total(un, quantidade) {
    return parseFloat(un.replace(',', '.'), 10) * parseFloat(quantidade.replace(',', '.'), 10);
}
window.onload = function() {
    id('valor_unitario').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
        var result = total(this.value, id('quantidade').value);
        id('total').value = String(result.toFixed(2)).formatMoney();
    });

    id('quantidade').addEventListener('keyup', function() {
        var result = total(id('valor_unitario').value, this.value);
        id('total').value = String(result.toFixed(2)).formatMoney();
    });
}

String.prototype.formatMoney = function() {
    var v = this;

    if (v.indexOf('.') === -1) {
        v = v.replace(/([\d]+)/, "$1,00");
    }

    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{1})$/, "$1,$20");
    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)\.([\d]{2})$/, "$1,$2");
    v = v.replace(/([\d]+)([\d]{3}),([\d]{2})$/, "$1.$2,$3");

    return v;
};
```

Creio que por estar estar buscando pelo id e como id é único o calculo só ocorre na primeira instância do elemento.
Pode ser que exista uma forma mais simples e funcional, mas como disse, não consegui resolver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, o `ID` deve ser único. Você pode usar o atributo `name` para identificar os campos.
Por exemplo assim:

```
<div class="qty">
  <input type="text" name="quantidade" maxlength="3" />`
</div>
```

Para obter todos os valores de quantidade, você pode fazer isso usando `jQuery`:

```
$('.qty').each(function () {
  var qtd = $(this).find('input[name=quantidade]').val();
  var val = $(this).find('input[name=valor_unitario]').val();
  var total = parseFloat(qtd) * parseFloat(val);
  console.log(total);
});
```

Fiz aqui um exemplo completo, você pode ver aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/ghzjf58w/

Claro que precisa colocar as tags do `php`, validar se os campos estão preenchidos, etc, mas isso deve te ajudar.

Comment: Olá @Ricardo Pontual, boa tarde, já agradeço a ajuda, como posso fazer para calcular ao sair do campo?

Comment: @adventistapr utiliza o onFocus no Jquery $().blur(sair do campo) e tem o  $().focus (entrar no campo) a titulo de curiosidade.

Comment: Você quer dizer ao sair do campo "valor_unitario"?

Comment: Isso mesmo @RicardoPontual.

Comment: Seria isso:
`$('input[name=valor_unitario]').blur(function() { suaFuncaoQueCalcula(); });`